# Comment character is not auto-indented in Bash and Python scripts

Tags: gvim

The cursor is on line 20. After pressing `o` the cursor (here depicted with a `|`) is placed below the `e` of `ext` as expected:

```
18 # set default extension
19 if [ -z "$2" ]; then
20   ext='pdf'
     |
21 else
22   ext="$2"
23 fi
```

If I now type a `#`, it is placed at the beginning of the line:

```
18 # set default extension
19 if [ -z "$2" ]; then
20   ext='pdf'
   #|
21 else
22   ext="$2"
23 fi
```

but expected is below the `e` of `ext`:

```
18 # set default extension
19 if [ -z "$2" ]; then
20   ext='pdf'
     #|
21 else
22   ext="$2"
23 fi
```

My `comments` are

```
comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
```

where

```
b:#
```

should be responsible for indent-aware comment repetition, but apparently the whitespace indentation (two blanks) is not recognized as such.

The same happens for me in Python files.

These are related settings in `.vimrc` (A `.vimrc` containing just these lines should reproduce the problem):

```
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set smartindent
set smarttab
set softtabstop=2
set tabstop=2
```

Again, `set autoindent` should produce the expected behavior, but does not.

Is it a bug or a feature? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your problem comes from setting 'smartindent'. The help has a short [explanation on your problem](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'smartindent'):

> When typing '#' as the first character in a new line, the indent for
>   that line is removed, the '#' is put in the first column.  The indent
>   is restored for the next line.  If you don't want this, use this
>   mapping: ":inoremap # X^H#", where ^H is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-H.
>   When using the ">>" command, lines starting with '#' are not shifted
>   right.

I believe this comes from the fact, that the '#' in the C language denotes a [pre-processor statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (macro like), however that is only valid if it starts at the beginning of a line.

Since Vim patch [7.4.069](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.069), this behaviour has been slightly adjusted with the ['cino-#'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#cino-#) option value for C-indenting which allows to shift '#' comment lines.

In general however, I would not recommend going with either ['smartindent'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'smartindent') (which is not so smart) or ['autoindent'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'autoindent'). Instead, I recommend using filetype specific indenting which is enabled using `:filetype plugin indent on` (see [`:help :filetype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype)) in your vimrc and uses indenting specific for the filetype you are editing (which often is a custom 'indentexpr' function, but can also be C like indenting, autoindent or anything else).